# Kohana 3, "Undefined Index" exception with m2m data adding

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

I posted this on official forum but with no result.

I am getting `Undefined index` enrollment error when trying to save data.

My pivot model:

```
class Model_Enrollment extends ORM  {
               protected $_belongs_to = array('page' => array(), 'menugroup' => array());
          }
```

Model_Page

```
protected $_has_many = array('templates' => array(), 'menugroups' => array('through' => 'enrollment'));
```

Model_Menugroup

```
  protected $_has_many = array('menuitems' => array(), 'pages' => array('through' => 'enrollment'));
//Overriden save() method in Model_Menugroup:
public function save() {
    if (empty($this->created)) {
         $this->created = time();
    }
    parent::save();
    $this->reload();
    if (! $this->is_global) {
      if (! empty($this->groupOwnerPagesId) {
          $page = ORM::factory('page');
          foreach($this->groupOwnerPagesId as $id) {
            $this->add('enrollment', $page->find($id));
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I did:

- I corrected table names in pivot model by changing them to singular
- I even now using the same name for pivot table / model = enrollment. The same as in tutorial. Just in case
- So the pivot table has name 'enrollment' and has 2 columns:  page_id , menugroup_id
- I tried to add pk in pivot table, but it changed nothing
- I tried to add/remove db relation  between pages/menugroups and pivot table (InnoDB) but with no luck
- I tried save all data in controller, but with the same bad result:(

I am still getting the same error:

`Undefined index: enrollment
in ORM line: $columns = array($this->_has_many[$alias]['foreign_key'], $this->_has_many[$alias]['far_key']);`

Could somebody tell me, what can be else wrong? I have no other ideas:(

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that tables are named this way;

```
Model_Page = table pages
Model_Enrollment = table enrollments
Model_Menugroup = table menugroups
```

If that doesn't get it to work, try defining 'model', 'foreign_key' & 'far_key' in `Model_Menugroup` and `Model_Page` 'has many' definitions, although it's a rule that "if you have to define table name, foreign keys or far keys manually, something is missed in the db design (actually, if you have to define anything that's supposed to be defined automatically) :)

If you still don't figure out where's the mistake, post all 3 tables CREATE queries and models here.

EDIT:

tested it, the problem is that you're passing model name instead of table name for "through". Try with 'enrollments' instead of 'enrollment' :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried what you suggest but still with the same error result. I'll paste my tables and models below.

Answer (score 0):

Table enrollments

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enrollments` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menugroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`,`menugroup_id`),
  KEY `menugroup_id` (`menugroup_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table menugroups

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menugroups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `is_global` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Table pages

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` tinytext,
  `description` tinytext,
  `template_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_main` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `header_on` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `footer_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sidebar_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longblob NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_modified` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`,`link`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link` (`link`),
  KEY `template_id` (`template_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Model_Enrollment

```
class Model_Enrollment extends ORM  {
    protected $_belongs_to = array('page' => array(), 'menugroup' => array());
}
```

Model_Page

class Model_Page extends Model_FlyOrm {

```
protected $_filters = array(
                        'title' => array('trim' => NULL),
                        'content' => array('trim' => NULL),
                        'keywords' => array('trim' => NULL),
                        'description' => array('trim' => NULL)
                   );

protected $_has_many = array('templates' => array(), 'menugroups' => array('through' => 'enrollment', 'foreign_key' => 'page_id', 'far_key' => 'menugroup_id'));

protected $_rules = array(

           'title' => array(
               'not_empty' => array(),
               'min_length' => array(3),
               'max_length' => array(100),

           ),
           'keywords' => array(
               'max_length' => array(255),
           ),
           'description' => array(
               'max_length' => array(255),
           ),
           'template_id' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'header_on' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'footer_on' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'sidebar_on' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'is_main' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'content' => array(
               'not_empty' => array(),
               'min_length' => array(10),
           ),
           'created' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'last_modified' => array(
               'digit' => array(),
           ),
           'author' => array(
               'max_length' => array(50),
           )
);

protected $_callbacks = array(
    'title' => array('is_unique'),
    'link' => array('is_unique'),
);

private $result = array('msg' => '', 'is_success' => NULL);

public function __construct($id = null) {
    parent::__construct('pages', $id);
}

public function get_pages() {
    return $this->order_by('is_main', 'DESC')->find_all();
}

public function save() {
    $this->create_link();
    if (! $this->_loaded) {
        $this->created = time();
    } else {
        $this->last_modified = time();
    }
    if ($this->is_main) {
        $old_main = $this->get_main_page();
        if ($old_main->_loaded) {
            $old_main->is_main = 0;
            $old_main->save();
        }
    }
    return parent::save();
}

public function values($values) {
    foreach($values as $key => $val) {
        if ($val == self::NOT_SET)
            $values[$key] = NULL;
    }
    return parent::values($values);
}

public function _delete($id) {
    $this->set_result($this->get_msg('pages.success.delete'));
    if (is_array($id)) {
            $pages = ORM::factory('page')->where('id', 'IN', $id)->find_all();
            foreach ($pages as $page) {
              if ($page->is_main) {
                    $this->set_result($this->get_msg('pages.fail.main_page'), FALSE);
              } else {
                  $page->delete();
              }
            }
    } else {
        $this->find($id);
        if ($this->_loaded) {
            if ($this->is_main) {
                $this->set_result($this->get_msg('pages.fail.main_page'), FALSE);
            } else {
                $this->delete();
            }
        } else {
            $this->set_result($this->get_msg('pages.fail.delete'), FALSE);
        }
    }
}

public function get_result() {
    return $this->result;
}

public function __get($name) {
    $value = parent::__get($name);
    if ($name == 'created' || $name == 'last_modified')
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $value);
    else return $value;
}

public function get_main_page() {
    return ORM::factory('page')->where('is_main', '=', 1)->find();
}

private function create_link() {
    $link = text::pl2en($this->title);
    $link = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\s]+/', '', $link));
    $link = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $link);
    $link = preg_replace('/^(-*)|(-*$)/', '', $link);
    $this->link = strtolower($link);
}

private function set_result($msg, $is_success = TRUE) {
    $this->result['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->result['is_success'] = $is_success;
}

private function get_msg($path) {
    return Kohana::message('messages', $path);
}

private function set_global_settings_if_required($global) {
    if (empty($this->template)) {
            $this->template = $global->template;
    }
    if (is_null($this->header_on)) {
            $this->header_on = $global->header_on;
    }
    if (is_null($this->sidebar_on)) {
            $this->sidebar_on = $global->sidebar_on;
    }
    if (is_null($this->footer_on)) {
            $this->footer_on = $global->footer_on;
    }
    if (empty($this->keywords)) {
            $this->keywords = $global->keywords;
    }
    if (empty($this->description)) {
            $this->description = $global->description;
    }
    if (empty($this->author)) {
            $this->author = $global->author;
    }
}
CONST NOT_SET = -1;
```

}

Model_Menugroup

```
class Model_MenuGroup extends Model_FlyOrm {

    protected $_has_many = array('menuitems' => array(), 'pages' => array('through' => 'enrollment', 'foreign_key' => 'menugroup_id', 'far_key' => 'page_id'));

    protected $_filters = array(
        'name' => array('trim' => NULL),
    );
    protected $_rules = array(
        'name' => array(
            'not_empty' => array(),
            'min_length' => array(2),
            'max_length' => array(100)
        ),
        'location' => array(
            'range' => array(0,2),
        ),
        'is_global' => array(
            'range' => array(0,1),
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'digit' => NULL,
        )
    );

    protected $_callbacks = array(
        'name' => array('is_unique'),
    );

    private $groupOwnerPagesId = array();

    public function __construct($id = NULL) {
        parent::__construct('menugroup', $id);
    }

    public function save() {
        if (empty($this->created)) {
             $this->created = time();
        }
        parent::save();
        $this->reload();
        if (! $this->is_global) {
            if (! empty($this->groupOwnerPagesId)) {
                $page = ORM::factory('page');
                foreach($this->groupOwnerPagesId as $id) {
                    $this->add('enrollment', $page->find($id));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function values($data) {
        parent::values($data);
        if (! isset($data['is_global'])) {
           if (isset($data['pages'])) {
               foreach( $data['pages'] as $key => $value) {
                   $this->groupOwnerPagesId[] = $key;
               }
           }
           $this->is_global = 0;
        }

    }

    public function check() {
        $result = parent::check();
        if (! $this->is_global) {
            if (empty($this->groupOwnerPagesId)) {
                $this->_validate->error('is_global', 'no_pages');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        $value = parent::__get($name);
        if ($name == 'created')
            return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $value);
        else return $value;
    }

    public function get_by_location($id) {
        return $this->where('location', '=', $id)->order_by('order', 'ASC')->find_all();
    }

    public function get_all_groups() {
        return $this->find_all();
    }

    public function get_parent_pages_if_exists() {
        if (! $this->is_global) {
            return $this->pages->find_all();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function get_items($group_id) {
        return $this->find($group_id)->menuitems->find_all();
    }
}
?>
```

I also noticed that I have one column name with mysql reserved word 'order', I changed it to 'ord' but with no positive result.

Comment: If you have extra information, you should put it in your question rather than posting an (as this post doesn't answer your question).

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

Instead of:

```
            $this->add('pages', $page->find($id));
```

I try add pivot!

```
            $this->add('pages', $page->find($id));
```

How can I be so blind!

Any way thank you very much Kemo for help and sorry for wasting your time by my big mistake.

Comment: (?) Can you correct your answer? You pasted two same codes and also you didn't marked your answer as the correct answer if it does solve your problem.